# how to achieve active state in a navigation for a one page website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a one page website. In this website, I would like to have the active section or "page" to be underlined in the navigation bar. Currently I have the link to display with underline after clicking on it. However, it stays underlined when I click to go to another active "page".

Here is how the navigation is set up in the HTML:

```
<div id="navbar" class="center">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
       <li><a href="#music">music</a></li>
       <li><a href="#videos">videos</a></li>
       <li><a href="#connect">connect</a></li>
       <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have written the rest of my code out in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GdePr/. Can anyone think of some solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just forgot to add jquery and set the code to run on dom ready: http://jsfiddle.net/GdePr/8/

```
$(function(){
    $('#navbar a').click(function () {
        $('#navbar a').css('text-decoration', 'none');//don't forget to reset other inactive links
     $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
     });
 });
```

But what i would suggest is to add the class `active` to the selected link and give it `underline` property in your CSS file so you can later in your script recognize current active link:http://jsfiddle.net/GdePr/14/

```
$(function(){
    $('#navbar a').click(function () {
        $('#navbar a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
     });
 });
```

CSS:

```
 a.active{
       text-decoration: underline !important; 
    }
```

Comment: I would like the underline to change as each section becomes active.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with MaveRicks answer slightly. You do need to wrap the code in a `ready()` function. However, to reset the other links, I would not jump into the DOM again. Make use of jQuery's `siblings()` function. It gets the elements on the same DOM level as the selected element, then does the specified function. By doing this, you are preventing the link you are clicking on to have two functions performed.

The selector would also take advantage of `parent()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navbar a').on("click", function () {
        $(this).parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

This finds the parent of the `a`, which would be the `li`. Then, it gets all of the siblings of the `li`, so this doesn't include the `li` of the `a` that was clicked. Then it `find`s all of the `a`s inside of those siblings. This will prove to be much more of a reusable function.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GdePr/16/)

Also, don't use `!important`. It can cause many problems for you down the road

Answer (score 0):

Can you try defining an active state for your links

```
#navbar a:active {text-decoration:underline;}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that does not help.