# How to show what div someone is on in navigation?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a single-page website and I'd like to show what subsection someone is looking at in the navigation, like an :active link in a navigation bar for multi-paged websites, but for a div. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: use a `:target` pseudoelement

Comment: (one of the first results in Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455070/how-to-achieve-active-state-in-a-navigation-for-a-one-page-website)

Comment: Your question is totally broad. What if one scrolls the page? What should than happen with the active states in the menu? Think about it. Come back with some real code and a real issue. Before you do so please read: [ask] and than make sure to create a [mcve]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a JQuery solution.

Luckily there's a plugin for that. :)

[ScrollNav - Jquery Plugin For Tracking Sections With Navigation](http://scrollnav.com/)